# Not able to get Regular Expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to set up validation regex on one of my text fields. 
A sample input looks like:

```
1364-lqap-10926
```

The validation formula is 4 digits, dash, 4 letters, dash, 5 digits (total length validation = 15).

I have tried with `\d{4})-([a-z]*[a-z])-\d{5}`, but unwanted values get matched, too.

Could you please suggest how to fix the regex?

Comment: what's the regex for "4Numeric"? then "4Alpha"? then "5Numeric"? THen you got it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: 4 + 4 + 5 = 13. Not 15.

Comment: i want one regex for this one...@gefei

Comment: Sorry total length 13

Comment: @stribizhev I think the hyphens account for the last two.

Comment: Can u guys please let me kow regular expressio for this one.itz urgent..@gefei ...@stru..@BIffen

Comment: @DattaSai It seems you've misunderstood how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: You say **Not able to get Regulat Expression**, but if you are not able it means you tryied something, is not it ?

Comment: yes... itried with \d{4})-([a-z]*[A-z])-\d{5}

Comment: @DattaSai And what's wrong with it (except for the missing bracket at the beginning)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for anchors (`^` and `$` forcing the check at the beginning and end of the string) as well, not just the patterns.

```
^\d{4}-[a-z]{4}-\d{5}$
```

Use with `i` option to ignore letter case.

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/eS7cN0/2)

Sample code:

```js
var re = /^\d{4}-[a-z]{4}-\d{5}$/i; 
var str = '1234-abcd-12345';
     
if (re.test(str)) {
   alert("found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

RegEx:

```
/[0-9]{4}-[a-z]{4}-[0-9]{5}/
```

`[0-9]{4}`: Matches four numbers
`\-`: Matches `-`
`[a-z]{4}`: Matches four alphabets from range a to z

Comment: No reason to escape the hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

The regex you are asking is pretty trivial and you should learn regexes by analyzing this one.

The regex following your behaviour is:

```
'/\d{4}-[a-zA-Z]{4}-\d{5}/'
```

Explanations:

> 4 Numeric

```
\d{4}
```

means that you want exactly 4 occurences of "\d" which is a number

> 4 Alpha

As num is not included in alpha, then you'll search for any occurence of letters that are exactly 4:

```
[a-zA-Z]{4}
```

> 5 Numeric

Same as 4 numbers but with a 5 instead of a 4 in the brackets (\d{5})

Comment: Thank @Tushar  /[0-9]{4}-[a-z]{4}-[0-9]{5}/     itz working but last number lmit up tp 6 also taking ,,,why?